# How to convert a matrix (rectangular) with dummy variables into a square matrix with numeric?

Tags: r, matrix, heatmap, igraph

I have this situation, in which I have about 200.000 observations ("source") that follow 8 different "target".
If they follow that target is 1 otherwise is 0 like in the simplified example below:

| source | target1 | target2 | target3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| source1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| source2 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| source3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Now, I want to know who follow more target and, consequently, how many times a same source follows more than one target, in other words, in each cell I want to know how many times both conditions are verified.
This would be the idea:

| (blank) | target1 | target2 | target3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| target1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| target2 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| target3 | 2 | 2 | 3 |

Comment: @DaveArmstrong, if I have a grouped_df, how can I modify your code to use it?

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)
dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~source,  ~target1,   ~target2,   ~target3,
"source1",  1,  0,  1,
"source2",  0,  1,  1,
"source3",  1,  1,  1)

mat <- dat %>% select(-source) %>% as.matrix()
crossprod(mat)
#>         target1 target2 target3
#> target1       2       1       2
#> target2       1       2       2
#> target3       2       2       3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I've modified and applied it to my case and it worked! Thanks a lot, this is how I did it:
`mat <- heat %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-source) %>%
  as.matrix()`

`mat <- crossprod(mat)`